# Criação de colunas em tabelas através de variáveis em java

Tags: java, table

Olá, gostaria da ajuda parta resolver o seguinte problema:
Tenho uma tabela, porém suas colunas podem ser definidas por variáveis definidas pelo usuário. Por exemplo, o usuário define a1, b1 e c1, a partir dai o programa cria uma tabela que deve conter uma coluna para cada variável.  Assim, o usuário pode definir até n colunas. Para a construção da tabela estou usando interfaces do netbeans.
Estou tentando achar uma solução para isso faz um tempo .... alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. O que já tentou fazer? Seria interessante adicionar o que já tentou na pergunta, para uma futura solução ter de onde partir.

Comment: Cara, eu não conheço sua solução, mas ficar criando novas colunas no banco tem 99,999999% de chance de ter uma forma melhor de fazer o q vc quer. Comandos DDL nunca deveriam estar à disposição dos usuários.

Answer (score 1):

Não crie colunas. Se você precisa que o usuário crie variáveis e especifica vários valores para cada uma delas, crie uma nova tabela que permite definir as variáveis para cada usuário. Os campos são:

- Id do usuário
- Nome da variável

Então crie outra tabela para armazenar os valores, com os campos:

- Id do usuário
- Nome da variável
- Valor da variável

Assim, nesta segunda tabela, ele pode ter vários valores.

Se o usuário pode definir apenas um valor por variável, simplesmente use uma nova tabela como a última:

- Id do usuário
- Nome da variável
- Valor da variável

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar resolver e volto para da um feed back.

Comment: Uma coisa que esqueci de falar, não estou mexendo com bancos de dados. E a tabela está sendo feita pela interface gráfica do neatbeans, gostaria de tentar criar as colunas de uma forma "dinâmica"