# Construção de tabela java a partir de um vetor como parâmetro

Tags: java, swing, array, jtable

Olá! Estou com problemas para construir uma tabela. É o seguinte, o usuário define uma série de variáveis que são armazenadas em um vetor. Gostaria de que as variáveis armazenadas neste vetor constituíssem o nome das colunas da tabela. O problema não envolve sql, mas sim variáveis passadas através de uma interface java construída pelo neatbeans.
Obrigado desde já.

um vetor de string (chamado coluna) é usado com a função Concatena vetor, que recebe duas arraysLists e armazena em uma terceira. Passando então para o arrayList resultado. os valores do arraylist resultado é passado para o vetor string str, retornando seu valor para a váriavel coluna.

Segue abaixo o Código:

Declaração arrays:

```
public ArrayList<String> colInput = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> colOutput = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Armazenamento nos arrays:

```
private void jButton1AddInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
       // TODO add your handling code here:
       int i = jList4.getSelectedIndex();
       if (i == -1) {
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Warning");
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, palavras.getString("Please, select a variable"));
       } else {
         tipoBotao = INICIAL;
         String aux = Table.getVars().get(i).toString();
         colInput.add(aux); 
         //System.out.println(colInput.get(j)); j++;
         pressionarVariavelInput(aux);
         escreverInput();
         //escreverFormula();
     }
 } 


 private void jButton2AddOutputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
       // TODO add your handling code here:
       int i = jList4.getSelectedIndex();
       if (i == -1) {
           JFrame frame = new JFrame("Warning");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, palavras.getString("Please, select a variable"));
       } else {
           tipoBotao = INICIAL;
           String aux = Table.getVars().get(i).toString();
           colOutput.add(aux);
           //System.out.println(colOutput.get(k));k++;
           pressionarVariavelOutput(aux);
           escreverOutput();
           //escreverFormula();
       }
   }
```

Chamada da tabela:

```
String[] coluna = this.ConcatenaVetor(colInput, colOutput);
Object dados[][]= new Object[][]{};       
jTable2 = new javax.swing.JTable(dados, coluna);
jScrollPane7.setViewportView(jTable2);
```

Função Concatena vetor:

```
String[] ConcatenaVetor(ArrayList colInput, ArrayList colOutput){
   int tam = colInput.size() + colOutput.size();
    ArrayList<String> resultado = new ArrayList<String>();
    resultado.addAll(colInput);
    resultado.addAll(colOutput);
    String[] str= new String[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < colInput.size(); i++){   
        str[i] = resultado.get(i);  
     }
    return str;

 }
```

Comment: Adicione o código na pergunta, sem ver fica dificil deduzir uma possivel solução. De preferencia, um código que seja [**reproduzivel**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Criação de colunas em tabelas através de variáveis em java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/139351/cria%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-colunas-em-tabelas-atrav%c3%a9s-de-vari%c3%a1veis-em-java)

Comment: Renan, é um pouco difícil ajudar sem nenhum código, tente postar a declaração do seu método (como você recebe este vetor)

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser duplicata da outra, mas como a outra não foi bem formulada e já tem uma resposta, melhor deixar esta mesmo. Renan, qual o problema enfrentado no código adicionado?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.swing.JTable$1.getColumnName(JTable.java:685)

Comment: Renan esse pedaço do erro não ajuda a identificar o problema. Adicione no final da pergunta a pilha de erros completa. Seu código não é reproduzivel, adicione um código que seja possivel simular sua tela.

Comment: Resolvido. Utilizei a criação DefaultTableModel para criar colunas conforme o usuário define as váriaveis. Somente retirando o conteúdo inicial da tabela e criando uma tabela vazia.

Comment: @RenanAlboy Adicione uma resposta a essa pergunta com a sua solução.